# Reading all files in a directory with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am attempting to read all the files (they will all be `.txt`) in a folder, and store the findings in an array.

This is currently what my code looks like:

```
fs.readdir(pathToMyDirectory, function (err, filenames) {
  if (err) throw err

  const allFiles = filenames.map(filename => {
    return fs.readFileSync(`${pathToMyDirectory}/${filename}`)
  })
  console.log(allFiles)
})
```

The result in my `console.log` is as follows:

```
[ <Buffer 2d 66 64 73 69 6e 64 66 6f 70 6e 64 66 70 73 64 6e 66 64 20 76 6b 20 64 6b 73 20 76 6b 6c 3b 73 64 20 0a 2d 20 64 66 64 73 6e 64 64 66 64 666c 6d 64 ... >,
  <Buffer 2d 20 69 6d 70 6c 65 6d 65 6e 74 20 53 75 72 72 6f 75 6e 64 20 53 6f 75 6e 64 20 73 65 74 74 69 6e 67 73 20 6f 70 74 69 6f 6e 2c 20 77 69 7468 20 41 ... >,
  <Buffer 2d 66 20 6f 73 69 64 62 6f 73 69 6f 76 6f 73 69 20 73 64 76 6f 6c 20 64 6f 64 73 20 62 6f 69 75 73 64 6f 64 73 20 6a> ]
```

To be fair, the size of the array if correct, I am just not getting the text displayed as I wanted.
What's going on? How can I make this work?

Comment: `readFile` as default will read in binary mode,  try `{encoding:"utf8"}` as the second param.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!